# Newbie question. KDE tries to load the main taskbar, after which disappears, after which cannot draw on the screen

Tags: unity, virtualbox, kubuntu, kde

Making my first steps in moving to Linux, and with a Linux book in my hands, trying to learn how properly work with it (currently through VirtualBox).

Trying to change the Window manager of Ubuntu 18.04 to KDE (kubuntu-desktop package). At the beginning all went well, but at my last iteration I applied driver suggestion, which stated to use "optimal" drivers for vbox gpu and toolbox, which I confirmed, moved to another task and triggered a reboot (believe that something still was in the middle).

Now I ended up with such a predicament:

1. After passing login manager, Plasma seems to be loading, for a second I see the taskbar drawing, after which it vanishes. It's still clickable, but even if to trigger the "Konsole" it doesn't get drawn (I see the wallpaper and this is all), but if to try and click the approximate position of it in the taskbar placeholder, I can see the unwrap animation (but after, it disappears). After this any interaction with the desktop stops.
2. If I try to switch to a tty terminal, since it's VBox, I see the screen size disappear, but it never loads - it simply grabs the left corner part of the wallpaper and all. Only way out is a reset.

I've returned to GDM, which started to loose the login screen for some reason (believe it started to work incorrectly after KDE installation), and trying to remove and cleanup KDE installation.

I did go by the suggestions of:

```
sudo apt remove kubuntu-desktop --autoremove
```

and

```
sudo apt purge kubunto-desktop
```

and additionally cleaning the ~/.config/ for configs

but currently I cannot remove-install KDE and making it work, believing that it still hooks up something of the old config (I had a different image for the login screen, and it still comes up).

In an ordinary case I would agree on "kill it with fire, lad" suggestion, but since I'm eager to get experience for the "Linux is indestructible" topic, I want to walk through this issue.

Answer (score 0):

First to clarify: KDE or GNOME/Unity (default for ubuntu) are desktops and Window managers are X server or Wayland. I presume you just installed second desktop and not Window manager. Generally if you want ubuntu with KDE you can try Kubuntu distro (not just package) - it offeres more stability that multi-desktop version. Olso removing KDE won't remove drivers which are apparently working for GNOME (login screen and default desktop) but seem to have some problems with KDE. I have been using Kubuntu on ViryualBox and it never behaved like this so I guess this problem is specyfic for multi-desktop configuration. If you have been messing with Window managers you should make sure you are running X server (normally default) and not Weyland. Weyland is experimental and still in early development and while testing it, I've got some invisible elements (apart from tons of other bugs). As for Linux being understucteble it is IF configuration  is done right unless you install some packege that removes bin/sh (real situation).

Comment: Yes, sorry about the mashup with "Window manager's and desktops". Still kinda new in these terms. On the thing about Weyland - not sure this to be the case. I had KDE working fine for the first few hours, and then a simple case of drivers and stuff, and I fail to restore it to a working state. By far, the question stands - how to do a full wipe of the package leftovers (yes, I understand that I can get a separate KDE distro, but with that approach I can install a fresh instance of Ubuntu, install the KDE package once again, and work until I get into the same mess).

Comment: You alredy did and it didn't worked. My guess would be that you need to uninstall these drivers insted of KDE. I am not sure how to do this for drivers installed by gui, but there should be something at settings/hardware (you can do it in GNOME/Unity, drivers are system-wide). But from my experance it was faster to reinstall system then to find and fix these kind of problems (only once I did fix it, but I knew location of wrong driver and uninstalled it from terminal). Thing is I have /home on seperate partition and script for config and software installation, so it was no loss.

Comment: As I went, I found issues with KDE environment in general, that made me re-think my idea of moving to KDE from Gnome (installed Kubuntu and even there I saw that Youtube videos have the audio/video sync issues). So, generally, this issue can be treated as suspended.